# Intercept emails sent out from my application so I can search and replace text within the body?

Tags: nginx, email, smtp

I have the following scenario.

My application is in Docker and all of the components within the application talk to each other using the container names.  However when the application sends outbound emails it uses a certain value that we can not change.  So rather than try and figure out everything I would have to change just to get this to work.  I wanted a way to maybe use nginx or another software to intercept outgoing emails perform a search and replace on the body and change the bad hostname to the applications hostname.

I know ngx_http_sub_module would work for http stuff, but i'm not sure if this works for email.  Anyone know of a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We accomplished this by using MailDev https://www.npmjs.com/package/maildev

We are taking in the email, then doing an email.text.replace.